# I cannot capture the click event when using jquery dialog inside backbone

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone-events

I have a jQuery UI dialog inside backbone app. I follow exactly the advise in this [post](http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-ui-modals/), but I still cannot capture the click event when clicking on "Login" button in my dialog. I keep getting this error (in jquery.js) in firebug:

```
TypeError: click is undefined
click.apply( that.element[ 0 ], arguments );
```

Here is my index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <title>Giip</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery_ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery_ui_theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <script data-main="js/others/app" src="js/libs/requires/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</html>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
//Setup app
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "../libs/jqueries/jquery",
        underscore: "../libs/underscores/underscore",
        backbone: "../libs/backbones/backbone",
        jqueryui: "../libs/jquery_uis/jquery_ui",
        text: "../libs/requires/plugins/text",
        templates: "../../templates"
    },  
    urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()
});

//Kick off app
require(["../views/giip/login_view"], function(LoginView) {
    loginView = new LoginView();
    loginView.render();                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

Here is my login_new.js:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "jqueryui",
    "text!templates/giip/login.html" 
], function($, _, Backbone, jQueryUi, loginTemplate) {
    var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

        login: function() {
            console.log("logging in...");
        },  

        events: {
            "click .ui-button": "login"
        },  

        render: function () {
            $(loginTemplate).dialog({
                title:"Login",
                autoOpen: true, 
                closeOnEscape: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: true,
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{ text: "Login" }]
            });                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            this.el = $("#dialogContainer");
            this.delegateEvents(this.events);
            return this;
        },  

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, "render");
        }   
    }); 

    return LoginView;
});
```

Here is my login_template:

```
<div id="dialogContainer" title="Create new user">                                                                                                                                                                                           
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="phamtranquocviet" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div class='clear-both vertical-spacer'/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**When I add a click event in the "render" function as followed, click event is captured and I can see "button clicked.." debug message in firebug. But that would not be the backbone way. Please help me find out what I did wrong? Thanks.**

```
render: function () {
            $(loginTemplate).dialog({
                title:"Login",
                autoOpen: true, 
                closeOnEscape: false,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: true,
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{ text: "Login" }]
                click: function() {
                    console.log("button clicked...");                                                                                                                                                                                        
                }
            });
            this.el = $("#dialogContainer");
            this.delegateEvents(this.events);
            return this;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have not passed the click call back function for the jQuery UI Dialog button options. why do you make things complicated, just make things cleaner like

login_template,  note that

```
<div id="dialogContainer">..</div>
```

changed to

```
<script type="text/template" id="dialog_template">
```

to use with underscore template, the full file is as below

```
<script type="text/template" id="dialog_template">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="phamtranquocviet" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <div class='clear-both vertical-spacer'/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx"   class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</script>
```

login_new.js

```
define([
"jquery",
"underscore",
"backbone",
"jqueryui",
"text!templates/giip/login.html" 
], function($, _, Backbone, jQueryUi, loginTemplate) {
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

    login: function() {
        console.log("logging in...");
    },  

    render: function () {
       var template = _.template( $("#dialog_template").html(), {} );
       this.$el.html( template ).dialog({
            title:"Login",
            autoOpen: true, 
            closeOnEscape: false,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            modal: true,
            buttons: { Login: this.login}
        });
        return this;
    },  

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    }   
}); 

return LoginView;
```

});

demo can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/0vk2qg87/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works. However, `events: {
            "click .ui-button": "doLogin"  
        }` is not used and thus strictly not backbone way of handling events. I understand your code in fiddle has "events", but it also works even when you take it out.